# Play framework, syntax highlighting in templates

Tags: html, scala, playframework-2.0

I have Intellij community edition, is there a way I can get syntax highlighting in templates? (the play plugin works only with Ultimate editions i've been told, and I don't know if that is required for highlighting (or if that even has highlighting))

Answer (score 1):

As Play 2.0 - is related to Web development, it's part of IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate. You can try it for free for 30 days to check if you really need it or not.

Comment: Does it have syntax highlighting?

Comment: Yes, it does. Works pretty fine.

Comment: I think I'm going to stay with a free s/w anyway, so let me ask this, does eclipse have syntax highlighting with play?

Comment: ScalaIDE (eclipse based) supports syntax highlighting/code completion etc for both templates and routes files.

Comment: @JamesRoper Thnks. I think I'll switch to ScalaIDE then.